How to add youtube into ip rule list?
Ordinary websites can be added by the command:
ip rule add to <site ip> table <some table>

But how can i add youtube rule?(for my table) Youtube has got great deal of ips.

Either they publish all IP-addresses they use (directly or for their CDN) and you can use those OR instead you use a (proxy) that is much more suitable to block websites by their FQDN rather than by IP-address - and as a general recommendation for rules that would span many IP-address (ranges) : use ipset

If you want to stop local users from accessing youtube, then your best bet is to set up your DNS server, hijack the domain & return NXDOMAIN. However, if people are smart enough, they will be able to get around it. In other words, no matter what you do, people will always find a way.

@BobGoddard hi/ No i want the opposite - let youtube traffic open through ip rules and tables , directing traffic into vpn. I live in Russia, so...

You can perform DNS lookups to get the current IP addresses for YouTube:
Using dig:
dig +short A youtube.com

This command will return the A records (IPv4 addresses) for youtube.com.
Using nslookup:
nslookup youtube.com

This command will provide detailed information, including IP addresses.
As YouTube uses dynamic IP addresses due to its extensive use of CDNs and load balancers, so the IPs may change over time. If you need a comprehensive list for YouTube, you have to query and update periodically.
